# Why does Wordpress prepend "wpid-" to my image file name?

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I upload an image to my Wordpress media library, "wpid-" is prepended to the file name. For example, if I upload an image called example.png, it becomes wpid-example.png.

I found that this is also the case on many WP websites. However, Slashgear, which runs on Wordpress, does not have this unwanted prefix prepended to their images.

I tried to look for answers on google but this has not been discussed before, at least that's what I think from what I got in the search results.

Could anybody guess why this could be happening? There is absolutely no code in my theme that acts on image names.

Comment: Did you find anything please? Did you achieve to delete the wpid ?

Comment: @androniennn Unfortunately not. If your website does not give as much importance to images as, say a Wallpaper download website, I think you shouldn't have to worry about it being added. I gave up on trying to remove it a long time back.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem is know, read this:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/xml-rpc-metaweblog-newmediaobject-overwrite-problem

Comment: That is a completely different thing.

Comment: Not so sure, following mentioned code I found class-wp-xmlrpc-server which is prepending "wpid" and: * As of WordPress 3.5.0, XML-RPC is enabled by default. It can be disabled
 * via the xmlrpc_enabled filter found in wp_xmlrpc_server::login().